# only display Pages which have children

Tags: wp-list-pages

Here is my website structure(wordpress pages)

```
 - HOME -
 - Tutorial -
    + PHP Tutorial +
    + Photoshop Tutorial +
    + Css Tutorial + 
    + HTML Tutroial +   
 - news -
    + November
    + September
    + May 
    + April
 - about -
 - contact -
```

How do I have the output just the pages which have children pages? 
so when I click tutorial page, the tutorial page has following list. (but pages list stays static when click subpages.

- Tutorial -

  - PHP Tutorial +
  - Photoshop Tutorial +
  - Css Tutorial +
  - HTML Tutroial +

I am using this code, but this only displays all children pages no parent.

```
<?php
  if($post->post_parent)
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=1");
  else
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
  if ($children) { ?>
  <ul>
  <?php echo $children; ?>
  </ul>
  <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to list only the pages with children? I'm not sure to understand well what you want to do :( If I'm right, you'll have to do something like this with get_pages() and generate your listing manually after:

```
// First get all pages
$pages = get_pages();  

// Then, get page IDs
if ($pages) 
{
    $pageids = array();
    foreach ($pages as $page) 
    {
        // Test if page has children
        if ( get_pages( 'child_of=' . $page->ID ) ) {
            // Save it if it's OK
            $pageids[]= $page->ID;
        }
    }

    $args = array(
        'title_li' => 'Pages with at least one child',
        //TODO: add yout display parameters here
    );
    wp_list_pages($args);
}
```

I think this could work!

Comment: Hmm, I think your problem is another one, but, with get_pages() you should do what yout want. Look at this example: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#List_parent_Page_and_all_descendant_Pages

Comment: thanks a lot. It prints all pages ... but only need itself and its children pages. thanks for the link

Comment: one more question, how can I make it static, it shows nothing when I click the 2nd level , How to make it only shows the itself and all children -Static? thanks